# Using Stripe with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, payment, stripe-payments

I'm a RoR newbie attempting to integrate Stripe with Devise so that I can register new subscribers of my app, and set them up to be charged monthly.  I've followed the Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) as well as reviewed the QA found here ([Using Stripe with Devise for Ruby on Rails Subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440509/using-stripe-with-devise-for-ruby-on-rails-subscriptions)), but still can't get it to work/fully understand what I'm doing wrong.  Essentially I want (if possible) to use my Devise User model and registrations controller, not have to create/use a subscriptions model/controller.

I placed the code from the Railscast into the appropriate places, but still receive error(s), for example:

```
NoMethodError in Users/registrations#create

Showing /app/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #7):

4: <h2>Sign up</h2>
5: 
6: <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
7:   <%= devise_error_messages! %>
8: 
9:   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
10:   <%= f.email_field :email %></div>
```

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

### models/user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:invitable

       has_many :org_roles 
      has_many :orgs, :through => :org_roles, :conditions => "role_id = 1"
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :orgs, :allow_destroy => true
      has_many :assigned_orgs, :through => :org_roles, :conditions => "role_id = 2" , :class_name => "Org", :source => :org
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :assigned_orgs
      has_one :user_detail
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_detail, :allow_destroy => true
      has_one :user_address
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_address, :allow_destroy => true

      has_many :subscription_plans

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_type_id, :orgs_attributes, :assigned_orgs_attributes, :user_detail_attributes, :user_address_attributes

      #STRIPE 
      attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

      def save_with_payment
      if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
      end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
      false
    end      
end
```

### controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
def create

  @subscription = User.new(params[:subscription])
  if @subscription.save_with_payment
    redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
  else
    render :new
  end

   super
...
```

### views/users/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", "application" %>
<%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>

<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div>Your Business Name:<br />
  <%= text_field_tag :org %></div>

<div>Please select a subscription plan: <br />
        <%= radio_button_tag(:subscription_plan, 1, :checked=>"yes") %>
        <%= label_tag(:subscription_plan_tag, "Small") %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:subscription_plan, 2) %>
        <%= label_tag(:subscription_plan_tag, "Medium") %>
        <%= radio_button_tag(:subscription_plan, 3) %>
        <%= label_tag(:subscription_plan_tag, "Large") %>
  </div>

<%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
    <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
  </div>
<div id="stripe_error">
  <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
</div>   

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>
```

### assets/javascripts/users/users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
      #alert(response.id)
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
      #alert(response.error.message)
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have run into the same issue.

Comment: No, I wound up using the SaaS RailsKit which now includes Stripe and has Devise.

Comment: The below solution should save you some cash ;)

Answer (score 4):

Based on how you've named your model (user) you should change @subscription -> @user.

Like this --

**controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
def create

  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save_with_payment
    redirect_to @user, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
  else
    render :new
  end

super
```